# Create Multiple List items, with one variable

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, list-form

I am creating a form in which there will be a title, date, task number, and assignment.  I have created the form to repeat, but need it to create multiple list items based on assignment.  So for instance if I have this assigned to four people, I need it to create four list items with the same title, date, and task number, however different assignment.

I have gotten as far as allowing the repeating items using infopath, however the title, date, task number and assignment show up on the first list item, but on the second and third list item I only see the assignment.

How do I get the other information to show?

Comment: I was actually able to create multiple instances using Infopath and then on each field running a rule: preceding-sibling::*[1]/Title

This did copy the data to the next section of the form, and inserted a second item.  However when I go open it back up to edit it, all the fields are empty.  What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You are describing a relational database scenario. Master/slave or Parent/child. This cannot easily be done with out of the box components. You need two lists. One has the jobs, and another has the assignments for each job.

SharePoint does not support this out of the box. You need to get creative.

Mark Rackley has a few approaches for SharePoint 2010 and earlier here: http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2010/12/16/creating-a-sharepoint-parentchild-list-relationshipndash-sharepoint-2010-edition.aspx

It's not a "click this box and you are done" approach. You need to live and breathe SharePoint and welcome JavaScript and JQuery into your tool set.

Once you understand how this works, it's a great tool to add to your SharePoint farm, so whatever time you need to understand the architecture of this approach will pay back.

Comment: I was actually able to create multiple instances using Infopath and then on each field running a rule: preceding-sibling::*[1]/Title This did copy the data to the next section of the form, and inserted a second item. However when I go open it back up to edit it, all the fields are empty. What is wrong here? –

Comment: And all the data shows up in the Datasheet View